# Enable CORS on Google App Engine: Unknown url handler type

Tags: google-app-engine, cors, gcloud

```
Activated service account credentials for: [***]
Updated property [core/project].
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/home/runner/work/tm/tm/build/app.staging.yaml]
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    static_files=None 
    upload=None 
    application_readable=None 
    static_dir=None 
    mime_type=None 
    expiration=None 
    require_matching_file=None 
    http_headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'} 
    position=None 
    api_endpoint=None 
    redirect_http_response_code=None 
    url=None 
    login=optional 
    auth_fail_action=redirect 
    secure=default 
    script=None
    >
  in "/home/runner/work/tm/tm/build/app.staging.yaml", line 6, column 1
```

I did read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element under the `CORS Support` area. It doesn't give really any information about required fields etc..

My `app.staging.yaml` file:

```
service: staging
runtime: nodejs12
handlers:
    - http_headers:
          url: /
          Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The headers that you specifying the `handlers` object in your `app.yaml` are for static files or directory handlers.

If you want your App Engine Standard app to accept CORS, you will have to set it on the app level.

A basic example would be the following:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

[Here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) are more examples of configuring CORS from `nodejs`